# What is the correct way to enable HTTPS on apache httpd VirtualHost, given a .pem file and a .key file?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I need to get https enabled on a webserver (RHEL 7.9, httpd 2.4.6).
We were provided a pem file, with the following format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
//
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and a .key file

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
//
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I've seen guides and tutorials online (for tomcat) that we need to use the `keytool` command to import the certificates such as

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ALIAS -file file.crt -keystore key.jks
```

However, I've found none that addresses when the certificate and key are in .pem and .key formats. For example, I used the following command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mysite -file mysite.pem -keystore mysite.key
```

and it gives an error:
**keytool error: java.io.IOEXception: Invalid keystore format**

On the configuration side, I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/home/admin/mysite.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/home/admin/mysite.key
    SSLEngine on
```

Which gives an error when running the httpd.service:

**Invalid command 'SSLCertificateFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**

What would be the correct steps to take when enabling https on apache httpd 2.4.6?

Comment: The error message quoted at the end indicates that you probably don't have the mod_ssl module enabled in your Apache configuration. After you enable it, `SSLCertificateFile` and other SSL-related configuration directives should be accepted. I don't understand the purpose of whole `keytool` related stuff you quoted, it should be enough just to put the `.pem` and `.key` files into locations specified in your config file.

Comment: `keytool` has nothing to do with Apache. It's a tool used to manage certificates in the Java ecosystem.